# How do I stop text element below typed text effect from moving on mobile?

Tags: wordpress

I have used the following code in a code element for a text type effect. It works well however on mobile because the typed text moves between 1 and 2 lines upon writing and deleting the text element below constantly moves up and down with it. How can I stop this from happening whilst still maintaining the typed effect on mobile?

This is the page   [https://www.didteach.com/typed-text/](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typed.js@2.0.132/dist/typed.umd.js"></script>
<div class="autotyping">Those who can, <span class="typing_text"></span></div>
<script>
//typing text animation script
var typed = new Typed(".typing_text", {
strings: ["teach", "tutor", "project manage", "design", "engage", "do data", "market", "code", "create", "do admin", "safegaurd", "coach", "do empathy", "communicate", "manage", "do inclusion", ],
typeSpeed: 50,
backSpeed: 25,
loop: true,
cursorChar: '|️',
});
</script>
<style>
.autotyping{
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
color: #FFF;
font-size:4.8em;
font-weight: 800;
}
.autotyping>span{
color: #8a386c;
font-size:1.1em;
font-weight: 700;
}
/*Shrinking for tablet*/
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.autotyping{
font-size:2.0em;
font-weight: 800;
}
.autotyping>span{
font-size:1.2em;
font-weight: 700;
}
}
/*Shrinking for mobile*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.autotyping{
font-size:1.9em;
font-weight: 800;
text-align: center;
}
.autotyping>span{
font-size:1.1em;
font-weight: 700;
}
}
</style>
```

I have been unable to find a solution to this at present.